# React.Js won't render my code - is it possible it's a webpack issue?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Trying to learn react.js at the moment and would love some help.

Basically I can't get this code to render and it's driving me insane and i'm wondering if it is to do with the code at all and is instead something to do with webpack not working correctly..

Here's the code - appreciate the help:

```
 - Body.jsx

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
/* Styles */
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
import Grid from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Grid';
import Jumbotron from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Jumbotron';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Col';

const BodyComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Jumbotron>
                    <Grid>
                        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large
                            callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting
                            point to create something more unique.</p>
                    </Grid>
                </Jumbotron>

                <Grid>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <h2>Heading</h2>
                            <p>Adipisicing ratione incidunt eaque expedita rerum porro inventore. Nihil sit ipsam iure
                                officiis sit eos at quibusdam natus dignissimos natus dolore! Vel doloremque ipsa alias
                                nihil harum laborum necessitatibus rerum?</p>
                            <p><Button>View details »</Button></p>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <h2>Heading</h2>
                            <p>Sit quia nemo quis enim provident porro eaque accusamus tenetur provident aliquid
                                commodi? Velit nesciunt maiores obcaecati totam praesentium sint vitae exercitationem
                                quaerat maxime iusto et! Consequatur aspernatur sit impedit.</p>
                            <p><Button>View details »</Button></p>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <h2>Heading</h2>
                            <p>Dolor aliquid dolores perferendis repellendus cum! Quam maiores blanditiis cupiditate
                                voluptatibus voluptas aliquid nisi placeat tempora. Rem debitis accusamus pariatur
                                officia corrupti. Architecto fuga reiciendis quos rem hic? Suscipit dignissimos.</p>
                            <p><Button>View details</Button></p>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


ReactDOM.render(
    BodyComponent,
    document.getElementByID('container')
);


This is the html part of the equation.

 - index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>React! React! React!</title>
    <span id = "Heading"> </span>

    <script src="dev/index.jsx"></script>
</head>

<body>
<span id='container'> </span>

<script src="output/myCode.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks again for the help everyone!

Comment: Console errors?

Comment: What is `dev/index.jsx`? What is `output/myCode.js`? How did you configure webpack? How should we know whether it's a webpack issue or not if you don't tell us anything about it (configuration, console output of build process, errors, etc)

Comment: If you are using Chrome, enable 'Breakpoint on exception' in the debugger, should stop at the error... Maybe the same option exists in Firefox

Comment: var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

var DEV = path.resolve(__dirname, "dev");
var OUTPUT = path.resolve(__dirname, "output");

var config = {
    entry: DEV + "/index.jsx",
    output: {
        path: OUTPUT,
        filename: "myCode.js"
    },
module: {
    loaders: [{
        include: DEV,
        loader: "babel",
    }]
  }
};

module.exports = config;

Thats the Webpack config file.

Comment: The dev/index.jsx is the javascript and myCode.js is where webpack outputs too